# How to add levels 10, 14 cards to the game?

Tags: arrays, swift, object, uicollectionviewcell, game-physics

My game starts with 8 cards or 4 pairs. Where should I insert the function and write it down correctly so that a new game starts if the win and + 2 pairs are added.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDataSource {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var timeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    var firstFlippedCardIndex:IndexPath?
    var model = CardModel()
    var cardArray = [Card]()
    var timer : Timer?
    var milliseconds: Float = 60 * 1000 // 30 sec
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        cardArray = model.getCard()
      
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        
        
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.001, target: self, selector: #selector(timerElapsed), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
              RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: .common)
    }

    @objc func timerElapsed(){
            
            milliseconds -= 1
            
            //Conver to seconds
           let seconds = String(format:"%.2f", milliseconds/1000)
          
            //set Label
            timeLabel.text = "time Remaining: \(seconds)"
            
            //When the timer has reached 0 will stop it
            if milliseconds <= 0 {
                
                //Stop the timer
                timer?.invalidate()
                timeLabel.textColor = UIColor.red
                
                //Check if theere are any cards unmatched
                ckeckGameEnded()
            }
          
             
            
            
        }
    
    func setupNewGame() {
        cardArray = model.getCard()
        let addCard = Card()
        cardArray.append(addCard)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: cardArray.count - 22, section: 0)
        collectionView.insertItems(at: [indexPath])
      
        collectionView.reloadData()
        
    }
        
   
    

    
    
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cardArray.count
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CardCollectionViewCell
        let card = cardArray[indexPath.row]
        
        // Set that card for the cell
        cell.setCard(card)
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        
        if milliseconds <= 0 {
                    return
        }        // Get the cell that the user selected
        let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CardCollectionViewCell
        
        // Get the card that the user selected
        let card = cardArray[indexPath.row]
        
        if card.isFlipped == false && card.isMatched == false {
            
            // Flip the card
            cell.flip()
            
            // Set the status of the card
            card.isFlipped = true
            
            // Determine if it's the first card or second card that's flipped over
            
            if firstFlippedCardIndex == nil {
                
                // This is the first card being flipped
                firstFlippedCardIndex = indexPath
            }
            else {
                
                // This is the second card being flipped
                
                // Perform the matching logic
                checkForMatches(indexPath)
                
            }
        }
        
    } // End the didSelectItemAt method
    
    // MARK: - Game Logic Methods
    
    func checkForMatches(_ secondFlippedCardIndex:IndexPath) {
        
        // Get the cells for the two cards that were revealed
        let cardOneCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: firstFlippedCardIndex!) as? CardCollectionViewCell
        
        let cardTwoCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: secondFlippedCardIndex) as? CardCollectionViewCell
        
        // Get the cards for the two cards that were revealed
        let cardOne = cardArray[firstFlippedCardIndex!.row]
        let cardTwo = cardArray[secondFlippedCardIndex.row]
        
        // Compare the two cards
        if cardOne.imageName == cardTwo.imageName {
            
            // It's a match
            
            // Set the statuses of the cards
            cardOne.isMatched = true
            cardTwo.isMatched = true
            
            // Remove the cards from the grid
            cardOneCell?.remove()
            cardTwoCell?.remove()
            ckeckGameEnded()
            
            
        }
        else {
            
            // It's not a match
            
            // Set the statuses of the cards
            cardOne.isFlipped = false
            cardTwo.isFlipped = false
            
            // Flip both cards back
            cardOneCell?.flipBack()
            cardTwoCell?.flipBack()
        }
        
        // Tell the collectionview to reload the cell of the first card if it is nil
        if cardOneCell == nil {
            collectionView.reloadItems(at: [firstFlippedCardIndex!])
        }
        
        // Reset the property that tracks the first card flipped
        firstFlippedCardIndex = nil
    }

    func ckeckGameEnded() {
            
            //Determine if there are any cards unmatched
            var isWon = true
            
            for card in cardArray {
                
                if card.isMatched == false {
                    isWon = false
                    break
                }
            }
            //Messing variables
            var title = ""
            var message = ""
            
            
            //If not, then user has won, stop the timer
            if isWon == true {
                
                if milliseconds > 0{
                    timer?.invalidate()
                }
                title = "BRAVO !"
                message  = "You`ve Won"
              
               
                
            } else {
               //If there are unmatched cards, check if there`s any time left
                
                if milliseconds > 0 {
                    return
                }
                
                title = "Game Over"
                message = "You`ve Lost"
                
            }
             //Show won/lost messaging
            showAlert(title, message)
            

        }
        func showAlert(_ title : String, _ message : String){
            //Show won/lost messaging
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
            
            let alertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: nil)
            
            alert.addAction(alertAction)
            
            present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

            
        }
        
    } // Endging of veiwController class
```

Here I am creating 4 pairs for the game and then removing the cards if they match.Tell me how to write down the order correctly, maybe rewrite the code somewhere. And can you show an example?

import Foundation

class CardModel {

```
func getCard() -> [Card] {
        
        //decare an array to store numbers we`ve already generated
        var generatedNumbersArray = [Int]()
        //randomly generate pairs of cards
      
        var generatedCardArray = [Card]()
        
        while generatedNumbersArray.count < 4  {
            //get a random number
          
            let randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(8) + 1
            //Ensure that the random number isn`t one we already have
            if generatedNumbersArray.contains(Int(randomNumber)) == false {
             
                //log the number
                print(randomNumber)
                
                //Store the number into the generatedCardArray
                generatedNumbersArray.append(Int(randomNumber))

                
                //create the first card object
                let cardOne = Card()
                cardOne.imageName = "card\(randomNumber)"
                
                generatedCardArray.append(cardOne)
                
                 //create the second card object
                let cardTwo = Card()
                cardTwo.imageName = "card\(randomNumber)"
                generatedCardArray.append(cardTwo)
                
                // make it so we only have unqiu pairs of cards
            } else {
                
            }
            
        }
        //Randomize the array
        
        for i in 0...generatedCardArray.count-1{
            // find a random index to swap with
            let randomNumber = Int (arc4random_uniform(UInt32(generatedCardArray.count)))
            
            // swap the two cards
            let temporaryStorage = generatedCardArray[i]
            generatedCardArray[i] = generatedCardArray[randomNumber]
            generatedCardArray[randomNumber] = temporaryStorage
        }
    //return
        return generatedCardArray
        
    }
```

}

Comment: Add the number of cards (or pairs) as a parameter to getCard and then use it instead of any hard coded value

Comment: Can I have a code example?

Comment: `func getCard(pairs: Int) {…` and then replace 4 with `pairs` in the code

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand

Comment: My pairs this is type "generatedNumbersArray"?

Comment: No it’s an Int, see my first comment